# "Security policy fail" when booting Arch Linux from USB drive

Tags: arch-linux, usb-drive, uefi, acer

I have copied the latest Arch Linux release (`archlinux-2016.08.1-dual.iso`) to an USB drive (32GB Transcend with USB 3.0) via `dd`. I'm trying to boot this drive on my Acer-Aspire VN7-791G, but it fails with the message

"Security policy fail"

I have already renamed the file `/EFI/boot/loader.efi` to `/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` (as suggested [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=169354https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=169354) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/676059)) but to no avail.

It didnt work with UNetBootin either.

How can I boot this drive?